# Android AWS S3 Upload TransferUtility error Upload part interrupted: time out and socket is closed

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

I have an Android app in which uploads videos to S3 using TransferUtility.
I am using Google Camera2 official code enable camera recording and also video upload.

It works in most devices, but in Xiomi MI 8 Lite, it crashes.

I thought it was a max size issue, but is not.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to fix it.

SDK version

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.5'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.5'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.16.5'
```

Here is my code:

```
private void uploadFile() {

    spinProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "XXX",
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    // get file to upload
    prepend = "android-" + interviewId + "-" + String.valueOf(questionId) + ".mp4";

    videoToUpload = CamRecordActivity.getOutputMediaFile(
            interviewId,
            questionId,
            this
    );

    TransferNetworkLossHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    //TransferNetworkLossHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onReceive(getApplicationContext(), new Intent().setAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

    final TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

    // connection timeout
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    // 30 seconds
    clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    // 5 min
    clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(300000);

    final TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
            "mobvideosappin",     /* The bucket to upload to */
            prepend,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
            videoToUpload        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
    );

    transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            Log.i("STATE: ", String.valueOf(state));

            if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED)) {
                Log.i("DONE: ", String.valueOf(state));
                spinProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                postAnswer.start();
                transferUtility.cancel(id);
            }

            if (state.equals(TransferState.FAILED)) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.tryagain));

                Thread th = new Thread((Runnable) transferUtility.resume(id));
                th.start();

                //finish();
                //startActivity(getIntent());
            }

            if (state.equals(TransferState.WAITING) || state.equals(TransferState.WAITING_FOR_NETWORK)) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.waiting));
            }

            if (state.equals(TransferState.CANCELED)) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.tryagain));

                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            Log.i("BYTES", String.valueOf(transferObserver.getBytesTransferred()));

            float _percent = ((float)bytesCurrent/(float)bytesTotal)*100.0f;
            final int percentage = (int) _percent;

            mProgress.setMax(100);
            mProgress.setProgress(percentage);
            textProgress.setText(String.valueOf(percentage) + "%");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            textProgress.setText(getString(R.string.tryagain));

            ex.printStackTrace();

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }

    });


}
```

And here is the log:

```
I/BYTES: 16777216
2019-12-20 17:20:46.053 3272-3937/com.jobconvo.entrevistanew E/UploadPartTask: Upload part interrupted: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: timeout
2019-12-20 17:20:46.056 3272-3272/com.jobconvo.entrevistanew I/BYTES: 17190538

...

I/BYTES: 8388608
2019-12-20 17:23:54.273 4672-4994/com.jobconvo.entrevistanew E/UploadPartTask: Upload part interrupted: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: timeout
2019-12-20 17:23:54.286 4672-4672/com.jobconvo.entrevistanew I/BYTES: 8696079
2019-12-20 17:23:54.302 4672-4994/com.jobconvo.entrevistanew E/UploadPartTask: Encountered error uploading part 
    com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: timeout
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:441)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3887)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:60)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:212)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:609)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:109)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createHttpResponse(UrlHttpClient.java:92)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:85)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:371)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212) 
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913) 
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3887) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:60) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:30) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:551)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306) 
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300) 
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:609) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:109) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26) 
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createHttpResponse(UrlHttpClient.java:92) 
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:85) 
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:371) 
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212) 
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913) 
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3887) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:60) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadPartTask.call(UploadPartTask.java:30) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to walk through some of the pages on Google and it seems that this type of exception occurs when the network goes offline when a transfer is in progress. The best way is to checkpoint the transfer and then resume when network comes back online.

Using a `TransferService` will register a callback with Android to get notified of the network connectivity changes. When network goes offline, the ongoing transfers are paused and when the network comes back online, the ongoing transfers are resumed. `TransferService` can handle this irrespective of the app being in background or foreground.

Using a `TransferNetworkLossHandler:` You can create an object of this handler and register it in your application. By doing so, when network goes offline, the ongoing transfers are paused and when the network comes back online, the ongoing transfers are resumed. `TransferNetworkLossHandler` only works when the app is in foreground. To make this work when your app is in background, you need to wrap the creation of this handler in an Android component (like a Service, etc.)

You'd require to declare the `TransferService` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You've also managed to use `onStateChanged()` try using `WAITING_FOR_NETWORK` state when you use `TransferService`.

Also the `TransferUtility` when used with `TransferNetworkLossHandler` pauses the transfers when network goes offline. However there are certain circumstances where the transfer cannot be paused and eventually fails with `TransferState` set to FAILED.

When app is in background and if there is an active transfer that is in progress and network goes offline, it depends how `TransferNetworkLossHandler` is registered with the app.
If you just registered `TransferNetworkLossHandler` in your app, you are responsible for app being in background and the handler would not be functional when the app is in background and hence the transfer could fail.
If you used `TransferService`, then it would work in Android API levels up-to 25 (pre-Oreo). However, if you run on a device running Oreo and above, you need to pass a valid notification object while starting `TransferService` using `startForegroundService`, else the transfer could fail.
There could be a race condition between the worker thread that is actually doing the transfer and setting the transfer state and the thread that receives the network broadcast from OS and pauses the transfer. This could result in the transfer erring out with FAILED state.

You can find a sample code [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/pull/1214/files) which would help you identify what's been missed in your code.

Hope that helps.